# Diferença entre versões do SQL Server Express?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Qual a diferença entre as versões do SQL Server Express do DreamSpark?

[image: SS]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há uma [página com informações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn954193(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/details.aspx?id=101064&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

#### SQL Server Express with Tools

É o banco de de dados com algumas ferramentas extras para ajudar da manutenção no SQL Server Express, LocalDB, e SQL Azure.

#### SQL Server Management Studio

Só possui as ferramentas de administração do SQL Server mas não o banco de dados, sozinho não serve pra muita coisa, é útil para por em um cliente que vai administrar um banco de dados remoto.

#### SQL Server Express LocalDB

É uma versão diferente que não é instalável. Ela é chamada diretamente pela aplicação sem precisar instalar (não roda como serviço). É mais leve e um pouco mais limitada (não possui *filestream*, replicação e não permite conexão remota). Não inclui ferramentas de administração.

#### SQL Server Express with Advanced Services

O mais completo, conta com o Reporting Services, Full Text Search e outros componentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta! Obrigado, baixei a versão With Advanced Services...