# Qual a diferença entre SQL Server, MySQL e outros SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli, pl-sql

Gostaria de saber mais claramente quais as principais diferenças entre SQL Server, PL/SQL e MySQL, e quais os principais pontos fortes/fracos de cada um.

Comment: SQL Server e MySQL são SGBDs (Sistema Gerenciador de Base de Dados), o primeiro da Microsoft e o segundo da Oracle, que, assim como muitos outros SGBDs adotam o padrão SQL (Structured Query Language) como linguagem de definição e manipulação. SQL é uma linguagem de programação de paradigma declarativo. PLSQL é uma linguagem de paradigma procedimental implementada para o banco de dados ORACLE. Aqui: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparativo_entre_sistemas_gerenciadores_de_bancos_de_dados_relacionais você encontra um comparativo entre SGBD Relacionais.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é o nome de um produto de [banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191199/101) da Microsoft. Obviamente ele usa SQL como linguagem de consulta e é principalmente de modelo relacional (ele usa outros modelos também, pode até ser usado como variações de [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101) apesar de não ter todos os recursos).

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) é um produto da Oracle para fazer a mesma coisa, podemos dizer que eles são concorrentes. Claro que muita coisa é diferente entre os produtos, mas ambos seguem o modelo relacional e tem uma linguagem SQL, apesar de [ser bem diferente uma da outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325933/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252582/101)).

PL/SQL é uma linguagem de programação específica para o banco de dados [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/) da Oracle. Note que é outro produto, diferente do MySQL. PL/SQL não é um banco de dados, é só a linguagem de programação e ela é diferente do SQL desses outros produtos. Claro que o básico é igual, mas tem várias diferenças quando sai do básico.

Inclusive PL/SQL tem extensões ao SQL que a torna uma linguagem de programação. SQL sozinha não chega ser uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101).

O SQL Server tem uma linguagem chamada T-SQL ([Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver15)) que seria o equivalente da PL/SQL, ou seja, é uma linguagem de programação completa para usar principalmente em [*stored procedures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101) do SQL Server.

Então fica complicado comparar uma linguagem de programação com um banco de dados. Daria para comparar o SQL Server com MySQL, mas qualquer um que tente provavelmente será tendencioso ou pelo menos pegará só alguns pontos.

O SQL Server é pago na maioria das suas versões, mas [não em todas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102120/101). O MySQL é gratuito de forma geral, mas é preciso algum cuidado com o uso, ele não é tão livre quanto as pessoas imaginam. Mas tem o MariaDB que é quase igual e é mais livre.

O SQL Server é tido como um produto mais completo e poderoso, fazendo mais otimizações enquanto que o MySQL é mais simples e pode ter melhor eficiência se a pessoa souber usar bem, além de ter certas flexibilidades diferentes do produto anterior. E ambos são vantagens e desvantagens deles, não é algo maniqueísta.

Volume de dados não é problemas para os dois. Há diversos casos que mostram isso claramente. Como a pessoa trabalha com eles é que determinará a capacidade dele.

Só porque algo tem SQL no nome não quer dizer que são a mesma coisa, inclusive NoSQL tem SQL no nome e quer dizer o oposto (ou quase, isso é tão bagunçado que tem NoSQL que tem SQL).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado. Essa foi realmente a resposta mais clara para mim. Acredito que nãos eja só uma dúvida minha, no fim das contas...